# Need help about normalizing database to 3NF

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I am currently working on a city travel guide application which let users explore places and plan trip.

In the account module, the following functions are to be considered:

1. User can register by providing primary email and password.
2. Registered users can add their personal details like they can add full name, secondary email, country and city.
3. User can setup their profile like they can add profile picture, Display name, places they have visited etc.
4. When they open own/ other's profile, their profile info (like photo and Display name) and statistics like their 'trip' count, 'likes' count, 'reviews' count are to be shown.

I have designed database tables for account module as follows:

```
 1. User_Account_details(user_id, primary_email, secondary_email, password)
 2. User_Personal_details(user_id, first_name, last_name, country, city)
 3. User_Profile(user_id, profile_picture, display_name)
 4. User_Statistics(user_id, trips_count, likes_count, reviews_count)
```

There are 3 more tables for cities and countries so that when user add country , then the app retrieve it from database and according cities are displayed in suggestions for city textbox.

```
 1. country(country_id, country_name)
 2. city(city_id, city_name)
 3. country_city_association(country_id, city_id)
```

Can anyone tell me the database tables are properly normalized to 3NF or not? And if yes, one more confusion: Should I normalize tables upto 3NF or BCNF? sorry, I am a newbie in database-design. plz help.

Comment: How you will store information there, will there be multiple entry in table `User_Personal_details`, `User_Profile`, `User_Statistics` for a single user, How you are storing address info there

Comment: @vijayp No, all tables are for single users and the user_id will be foreign key from User_Account_details to each other table.

Comment: I See all those four tables can be changed to two table, one for saving all the login related info and other for saving aothe user info

Comment: @vijayp Can you answer my question? i'll highly appreciate.

Comment: what are country and city in `User_Personal_details` Id from country_city_association?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need four tables for the user account data. Each user only has one primary email, one secondary email, one first name, one profile picture, one count of trips etc. If there's only one of each entry per user, why not put them all in the same table?

You can set a lot of the fields to be nullable so that they don't all have to be filled in, and you might also want a "registration status" field to show if they're a guest or a registered user.

If you only want to show users certain parts of another user's profile, you don't need to store the publicly available information in a separate table, you can use a query like this:

```
select profile_picture, display_name, trips_count, likes_count, reviews_count
from user_table where user_id = @SelectedUser
```

Comment: But, will it not break the rules of normalization?

Comment: @xyz which rule would it break?

Answer (score 1):

For user details, I would suggest to have two tables and one for saving User Address

```
 User_Account_Details(user_id, primary_email, secondary_email, password)

 User_Personal_Details(user_id, first_name, last_name, profile_picture,
                       display_name)

 User_Address(user_id,country, city)

 User_Statistics(user_id, trips_count, likes_count, reviews_count)
```

Now, you can go for adding more columns in `User_Address` table for saving more information in address.

Comment: thanks..But the statistics are to be counted by stored procedure and they are to be counted from other tables. Can't I make the separate table for it?

Comment: statistics will change frequently right? and do you need to save save other info also for satictics like tripsId, reviewId etc?

Comment: Ya...statistics will be changed frequently.

Comment: Yes, you can go for adding one `User_Statistics` tables(edited my answer), as these table will keep a different set of info in a seperate table. The rest design looks good to me